# Virtual Box Kernel error

Tags: kernel, 14.04, virtualbox, kubuntu, lts

I am using kubuntu in my laptop
i have installed virtual box in kubuntu 14.04 lts
but when i start virtual machine it gives me error:

> Failed to open a session for the virtual machine ub.
>
> VT-x is disabled in the BIOS. (VERR_VMX_MSR_VMXON_DISABLED).
>
> Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
> Component: Console
> interface: IConsole {8ab7c520-2442-4b66-8d74-4ff1e195d2b6

details of my kubuntu is

> Linux Tank-PC 3.13.0-27-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 15
> 18:06:16 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

and while installing i got error about kernal version

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
dkms fakeroot libfakeroot libgsoap4 virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-qt
Suggested packages:
dpkg-dev debhelper virtualbox-guest-additions-iso vde2
The following NEW packages will be installed:
dkms fakeroot libfakeroot libgsoap4 virtualbox virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-qt
0 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 21.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 86.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe libgsoap4 amd64 2.8.16-2 [525kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse virtualbox amd64 4.3.10-dfsg-1 [15.5 MB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main dkms all 2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5 [64.4 kB]                     .0 kB/s 3min 33s
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse virtualbox-dkms all 4.3.10-dfsg-1 [538 kB]          
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse virtualbox-qt amd64 4.3.10-dfsg-1 [4,592 kB]        
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libfakeroot amd64 1.20-3ubuntu2 [25.4 kB]                 
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main fakeroot amd64 1.20-3ubuntu2 [55.0 kB]                    
Fetched 21.3 MB in 4min 15s (83.5 kB/s)                                                                       
Selecting previously unselected package libgsoap4:amd64.                                           
(Reading database ... 152414 files and directories currently installed.)                           
Preparing to unpack .../libgsoap4_2.8.16-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgsoap4:amd64 (2.8.16-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox.
Preparing to unpack .../virtualbox_4.3.10-dfsg-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox (4.3.10-dfsg-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package dkms. 
Preparing to unpack .../dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5_all.deb ...
Unpacking dkms (2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox-dkms.
Preparing to unpack .../virtualbox-dkms_4.3.10-dfsg-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox-dkms (4.3.10-dfsg-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox-qt.
Preparing to unpack .../virtualbox-qt_4.3.10-dfsg-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox-qt (4.3.10-dfsg-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfakeroot:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libfakeroot_1.20-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libfakeroot:amd64 (1.20-3ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package fakeroot.
Preparing to unpack .../fakeroot_1.20-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking fakeroot (1.20-3ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.2-0ubuntu3) ...
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mms'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmst'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmsu'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/pnm'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspt'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspu'
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libgsoap4:amd64 (2.8.16-2) ...
Setting up virtualbox (4.3.10-dfsg-1) ...
* Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules                                                                           [ OK ] 
* Starting VirtualBox kernel modules                    
* No suitable module for running kernel found
                                                                                                [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript virtualbox, action "restart" failed.
Setting up dkms (2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5) ...
Setting up libfakeroot:amd64 (1.20-3ubuntu2) ...
Setting up fakeroot (1.20-3ubuntu2) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/fakeroot-sysv to provide /usr/bin/fakeroot     (fakeroot) in auto mode
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Setting up virtualbox-dkms (4.3.10-dfsg-1) ...
Loading new virtualbox-4.3.10 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.13.0-27-generic
Building initial module for 3.13.0-27-generic
Done.
vboxdrv:
Running module version sanity check.
- Original module
- No original module exists within this kernel
- Installation
- Installing to /lib/modules/3.13.0-27-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxnetadp.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
- Original module
- No original module exists within this kernel
- Installation
- Installing to /lib/modules/3.13.0-27-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxnetflt.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
- Original module
- No original module exists within this kernel
- Installation
- Installing to /lib/modules/3.13.0-27-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxpci.ko: 
Running module version sanity check.
- Original module
- No original module exists within this kernel
- Installation
- Installing to /lib/modules/3.13.0-27-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod...........

DKMS: install completed.
* Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules                                                                    [ OK ] 
* Starting VirtualBox kernel modules                                                                   [ OK ] 
Setting up virtualbox-qt (4.3.10-dfsg-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6) ...
```

help me guys...every answer will be appreciated thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to reboot your computer, go to your BIOS setup and enable VT-x.
Once that is done, and you boot Ubuntu again, VirtualBox won't give you that error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make these changes in your BIOS. Also after enabling as above you can confirm the instrucrtion set/flags from support from "/proc/cpuinfo". Look for vtx or vmx flags have virt-support on the CPU.  OR look try the "lscpu" cmd and look for "Virtualization:        VT-x"

Comment: can you tell me how to do it step by step

Comment: Looks like your issue is resolved, but can also check with the cmd: "lscpu | grep -i virt" if vt-x is enabled

Comment: thank you...i have also tried your method to check and it also worked.thank you so much